# Regex with blank characters

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that matches the a string with the following properties:

1. Contains exactly 3 characters.
2. Can contain blank spaces.
3. At least one character should be non blank space.
4. Only blank spaces and digits are allowed.

See examples below. I am using `b` to represent a blank space character.

**Valid examples**

```
123
b12
bb1
1bb
12b
```

**Invalid examples**

```
bbb
1b2
```

I've tried

```
 [0-9 ]{1, 3}
```

The above regular expression matches strings with all characters blank. Can someone help me with writing a better regular expression?

Comment: Why is `1b2` invalid? It doesn't violate any of the four rules you stated above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be written out in full. Furtunately, if you mean you want only numbers optionally preceded or followed by spaces (as seen from the `1b2` bit which isn't allowed), there is only a small number of possibilities.

```
([0-9]  )|([0-9]{2} )|([0-9]{3})|(  [0-9])|( [0-9]{2})
```

There you have it.

Of course, if you can do the checking for length=3 outside of the regex, the regex itself can be shortened to

```
([0-9]{1,3}[ ]*)|([ ]*[0-9]{1,3})
```

Answer (score 9):

I would use lookaheads for this:

```
^(?=.*\d)[\d ]{3}$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^         # Start of string
(?=.*\d)  # Assert presence of at least one digit
[\d ]{3}  # Match exactly three digits or spaces
$         # End of string
```

Comment: i test this regex using pcre, it dont even match 123

Comment: @slier: I'm sorry, I had a spurious `^` in the character class. Silly me.